# How to implement multiple inheritance in SQL?

Tags: multiple-inheritance

In a relational database, if there is a Student table and Employee table, and a third table StudentAsst who indicates a multiple inheritance from both Student and Employee tables.

My Question: in SQL how to create the StudentAsst, and what is its primary key?

Comment: Databases don't have inheritance, multiple or otherwise. Each table is independent.

Comment: what are the relations? employee to student, student to asst, employee to asst ? (one to many etc)

Answer (score 1):

Since a StudentAsst is-a Student and is-an Employee, your table could have a primary key consisting of EmployeeID and StudentID:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentAsst
(StudentID int, 
 EmployeeID int,
 ...,
 CONSTRAINT PK_StudentAsst PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, EmployeeID),
 CONSTRAINT FK_Employee FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId)
            REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID),
 CONSTRAINT FK_Student FOREIGN KEY (StudentID)
            REFERENCES Student(StudentID)
 )
```

[Here is an example](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server) of a similar situation with Student, Teachers and Parents.

Comment: I should add as a note that even though this might answer your question, you should ask yourself why you need the StudentAsst table. If there are no fields unique to a student assistant, it would be easier to have foreign key from your Student table to the Employee table, indicating that a student is also an employee.